Converting latitude hexadecimal values (Latitude Dec, Latitude Min, Latitude Sec & Latitude Sign) to decimal degrees format
I have a below latitude value in hexadecimal format, How can I convert the values to decimal degrees format using TQL query
Latitude_Dec  - 13,623
Latitude_Min1 - 12,343
Latitude_Min2 - 11,826
Latitude_Min3 - 13,107
Latitude_Sec  - 11,342
Latitude_Sign - 0
I have the above values in hexadecimal format, I need to convert it to decimal degrees format, if converted successfully the latitude value will be (57.1173933333333) as per the above values.
I need it to be converted using the TQL(Timeseries Query Language) query language.
